# Use View Email as Web Page link visible in webpage?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We use the ExactTarget email out-of-box tool 'Use View Email as Web Page' in email template. When we go to webpage, we see the link `Use View Email as Web Page` again.  Can we disable them when we see the email as Webpage?

thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but it'll involve the AMPScript in your email.  There's a Personalization String named [_messagecontext](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/) that you can use to detect a VAWP scenario:

```
%%[ if _messageContext != "VAWP" then ]%% 

<a href="%%view_email_url%%" alias="VAWP">View as a Web Page</a>

%%[else]%% 

Alternate content

%%[endif]%%
```